# Does viewing the Map pause the game?

Tags: dont-starve

I noticed that when the hounds are targeting me, they keep attacking me even when I'm viewing the map, and eventually they kill me and the map is still open. I even was resurrected once at a touchstone when this happened. Another time I left the game in map view and came to see myself dead in the middle of killer bee hives.

So I became concerned that viewing the map still makes the time go by and if the night comes, I might be killed by Charlie, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I can't figure out how it works still.

Does viewing Map pause the game? Or does it only pause the game under certain conditions?

Comment: Have you installed any mods that may have broken this feature?  I'm not sure of any in particular, but there are definitely mods that replace native game files.

Comment: I'm starting to think this may have happened due to opening console.

Comment: Opening the console typically pauses everything on screen, too. But, if you restart the game is should fix it.

Comment: And there's the tricky part: while the map is already pausing the game, I believe, opening console calls the same method that toggles the pause back.

Comment: I tested this and it is true. Added below as answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Viewing the map does pause the game.

If, however, you are on the map screen and you load the console by accidentally hitting <kbd>`</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will cause the game to un-pause while the map screen is still up.

The remedy for this:  Hit <kbd>Control-L</kbd> to close the console.  Then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to turn off the map.  Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to reload the map screen, and you will pause properly again.

Comment: I guess this would have sufficed as a comment

Comment: @Edeph - Perhaps. Yet, it does offer information regarding the underlying cause of the problem and the solution to it. Hence, it is actually a more complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, viewing the map pauses the game. The best way to test it yourself is to position yourself next to an animal and check if it changes it's position after a while while you were viewing the map.

Comment: This is my experience as well but is in direct contradiction to his experience of dying while the map is open.

Comment: Perhaps more testing is needed I will come back shortly after some experiments.

Comment: After some more testing, indeed viewing the map pauses the game. I was looking at a bird and as soon as it set flight, I pressed tab, waited 10 seconds, then resumed and the bird was in the same spot on the screen, flying away. I tried the same with the giant one-eyed birds and it worked out the same.